# Method for deleting files that are not in the list deletes everything in directory

Tags: c#

I have searched on this site for best ways to delete all files in a folder, which ARE NOT specified in a list of filenames. I've came across this. It should work, but it doesn't. I tried to feed it with a List of filenames, but in the end it always wants to delete every file... Anybody can see the problem in the syntax, please?

```cs
public void DeleteFilesExcept(string directory, List<string> excludes)
{
   var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(x => !excludes.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)));
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
      //Trace.WriteLine("Smazalo by se " + file);
      System.IO.File.Delete(file);
   }
}
```

**Literally my logs:**

Excludes contains: C:\Users\benze\OneDrive\Plocha\Repozitáře\zeroapp-raven-launcher\ZeroApp\bin\Debug\Addons#44RR_Main\index.xml

DeleteFilesExcept would delete: C:\Users\benze\OneDrive\Plocha\Repozitáře\zeroapp-raven-launcher\ZeroApp\bin\Debug\Addons#44RR_Main\index.xml

Comment: Have you tried debugging your code? What are the values inside `excludes` and `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory)`? See: [MCVE].

Comment: I have tried, unfortunately. I'll update the question with more info, gimme a sec.

Comment: Remember that casing matters when comparing strings

Comment: What does `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory)` give you a count of? Then what does `System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(x => !excludes.Contains(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)))` give you a count of? Does `excludes` contain valid paths or anything at all?

Comment: System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x) returns just the name of the "folder" if you give the directory as a parameter. It doesn't return the file names in that folder.

Comment: `System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)` returns just the filename without path. so you are comparing the full path of a file with a filename which returns always `false`

Comment: @SebastianSiemens that might be a good point, will try fixing that in a sec.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory)` returns a list of full file paths (strings).

`System.IO.Path.GetFileName(x)` returns just the filename without path. so you are comparing the full path of a file with a filename which returns always false.

Try following code:

```
public void DeleteFilesExcept(string directory, List<string> excludes)
{
   var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(x => !excludes.Contains(x));
   foreach (var file in files)
   {
      //Trace.WriteLine("Smazalo by se " + file);
      System.IO.File.Delete(file);
   }
}
```

Comment: @benedikz Are you sure about that? It doesn't work for me!

Comment: Really sure, you only have to remove `System.IO.Path.GetFileName()` from the for it to be
`var files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(directory).Where(x => !excludes.Contains(x))` as said by Sebastian